# Updating the Progress Bar achieved in the New View

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-inflate

I want to Update the Progress bar in my application.

I have created a new view by making use of inflater and in that newly created view I want to show the Horizontal Progress Bar Updating.

How can I do that particularly?

Also I got to know that when We create a new view by Inflater, we need to add it to the Current Activity Class by addContentView(), I don't know how to do these though I have tried a lot till now.

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as you don't provide code, let me search my crystal ball... wait... OK, there it is. You have something like this:

```
View someView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_with_progress_bar, null);
```

In order to access your `ProgressBar`, you have to use the `findViewById` method:

```
ProgressBar yourProgressBar = (ProgressBar)someView.findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_progress_bar);
// you can know modify the progress bar: yourProgressBar.setBlahBlah
```

In order to add the view that contains the progress bar to you current activity, you have to have a reference to the container that you previously set. So, I guess you previously did: `setContentView(R.layout.something);`, then you have a layout called `something.xml`; that layout contains a `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc.; my crystal ball can't see that clearly). Then, you need to set an ID to that container, create a reference, and add your newly created view to it:

```
// in your onCreate method
setContentView(R.layout.something);

// let's suppose it's a LinearLayout
LinearLayout mainContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.id_you_gave_to_container);

// blha blah... the rest of your code. Keep in mind that you will
// probably have to declare the mainContainer outside the onCreate method

// here, you have already inflated your view, and want to add it to your activity
mainContainer.addView(someView);
```

Comment: Sorry for not posting my code and Thanks a lot for your answer(I truly believe you might be having a Crystal Ball now as my code is just as you have shown), can you please tell me where exactly I should write this line: "LinearLayout mainContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.id_you_gave_to_container);" because actually I am doing my code in the Click event of the Button in the Class that extends BaseAdapter. 
Again Thanks a lot Cristian.